# Is this fair or foul?

Tags: rules, baseball

If a ball is batted in foul territory and is fielded in foul territory but the ball bounces off the fielders glove and lands in fair territory, is it fair or Foul?

Answer (score 3):

The ball is foul and the play is dead.

The [rulebook](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf) reference defines a fair ball (Definitions section, page 142 in linked version):

> A FAIR BALL is a batted ball that settles on fair ground between home
> and first base, or between home and third base, or that is on or over
> fair territory when bounding to the outfield past first or third base,
> or that touches first, second or third base, or that first falls on
> fair territory on or beyond first base or third base, or that, **while
> on or over fair territory touches the person of an umpire or player**,
> or that, while over fair territory, passes out of the playing field in
> flight.
>
> A fair fly shall be judged according to the relative position
> of the ball and the foul line, including the foul pole, and not as to
> whether the fielder is on fair or foul territory at the time he
> touches the ball

The ball in the scenario touched a person not over fair territory, but over foul territory.  The place it eventually struck the ground after such a contact is not relevant.